# Using Angular ui-tinymce with RequireJS?

Tags: angularjs, tinymce-4, angular-ui-tinymce

I have been using the `ui-tinymce` directive in an AngularJS application and it works fine.  I am able to provide options to the editor like language, menus, etc.

I have started using RequireJS to load Angular, `angular-ui-tinymce`, `tinymce`, etc.  Now the `ui-tinymce` directive seems to no longer be able to setup an editor with the options provided in the directive like language.

Not sure where the problem lies but some how, when the `ui-tinymce` directive calls `tinymce.init()` for the `<textarea>` where the directive is, it ignores the options.  Since this is occuring when RequireJS is used, it leads me to thinking that is has something to do with how `tinymce`, `ui-tinymce` and `angular` are being loaded.

In my RequireJS config, I have the following with regards to `tinymce` which I have seen in answers to how to use `tinymce` with RequireJS:

```
requirejs.config({
   baseUrl: '/js',
   paths: {
    tinymce: 'tinymce/tinymce.min',
   },
   shims: {
    'tinymce': {
        exports: 'tinymce',
        init: function () {
            this.tinyMCE.DOM.events.domLoaded = true;
            return this.tinyMCE;
        }
    },
}
```

Has someone else experienced this problem and can give me pointers to how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my issue was not related to the use of `RequireJS`.  TinyMCE works fine with both `RequireJS` and `ui-tinymce` using the `requirejs.config()` shown in my question.

My problem had to do with the configuration settings passed to `tinymce.init()` which were wrong.  In the transition to `RequireJS`, I also modified how the initialization was done and that's how the problem was introduced.